# What is the difference between config.time_zone and config.local_zone and when should both be set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, environment

What is the difference between `config.time_zone` and `config.local_zone`? Is there a situation when should both be set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)**  `config.time_zone`

Rails gives your ability to configure application **time zone**. It's as easy as `Time.zone = 'EST'`.

So setting `config.time_zone` in your `application.rb` will eventually do the same. And this is the right thing to do since we don't want to depend on **server time zone**.

In your `application.rb` (Rails 3) file, you can set the default timezone:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

**2)** `config.local_zone`

It displays the system local time.

So if you really must have **local time** in the db then lie to Rails by
setting `config.time_zone` to UTC, this tells it that it is to assume
that timestamps are already in UTC so it will not need to change them
to get them into what it thinks is UTC.

`config.active_record.default_timezone` determines whether to use `Time.local` (if set to :local) or `Time.utc` (if set to :utc) when pulling dates and times from the database. The default is `:utc` for Rails, although Active Record defaults to `:local` when used outside of Rails.